# How to flash an ATMEGA2560 using a WIZnet 5500?

Tags: ethernet

I am wondering if anyone has ever flashed a ATMEGA2560 utilizing a WIZnet 5500? I have looked at [this bootloader package](https://github.com/per1234/Ariadne-Bootloader) but it only supports the 5100. I may have to do it myself but am a little worried as there doesn't seem to be any support/documentation online and I am not the best programmer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The latest Ariadne bootloader from 'codebender' is in [his 'personal' GitHub repository](https://github.com/loathingKernel/ariadne-bootloader). It has W5500 support. Per created [his fork](https://github.com/per1234/Ariadne-Bootloader) with better documentation and a hardware package earlier. The loathingKernel's repo still lacks good documentation.

I installed Per's Ariadne package over Board Manager and then I replaced the files in Per's package with files from loathingKernel's repo. The I flashed the bootloader to Mega without problems and the Ariadne bootloader worked for me over W5500.

I configured the upload from IDE too.

Comment: i trying to do same, but use arduino nano + wiznet5500 board. Default configuration with tftp server on 192.168.1.128 is started, but not responing for my tftp client. And I suspect 7KB of memory for the Ariadne bootloader and 26KB for the main firmware will overflow flash-memory microcontroller memory, since there is only 30KB. I'll try Mega, like you

Comment: @hwak, did you reset to bootloader. for Mega there is a better library now https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA

Comment: thank you. It’s a pity that Mega is very large. I would like something smaller so that it fits into standard electrical sealed boxes 100х100 millimeters

Comment: @hwak, Nano Every is good, but it has no OTA solution yet. I plan to try to make one over SD card and SD bootloader. but I have too many Arduino plans and not enough free time for it.